# c# Split xml values with newline

Tags: c#

I have this problem. I need to read xml and get All the values in the tag (there are many), my problem is that they all appear in 1 line like this:

`111/222/333`

but I need them like this

```
111/
222/
333
```

How would I do It?

My current code Is

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument2 = new XmlDocument { XmlResolver = null };
xmlDocument2.Load("http://fota-cloud-dn.ospserver.net/firmware/" + csc + "/" + model + "/version.test.xml");
XmlNodeList z = xmlDocument2.GetElementsByTagName("upgrade");
string k = z[0].InnerText;
File.WriteAllText("z.txt", k);
```

Example xml: http://fota-cloud-dn.ospserver.net/firmware/SEB/SM-A600FN/version.test.xml

```
<upgrade>
    <value rcount="15" fwsize="190580485">A600FNXXU5CTA1/A600FNOXM5CTA1/A600FNXXU5CTA1</value>
    <value rcount="1" fwsize="492203630">A600FNXXU2ARG5/A600FNOXM2ARF7/A600FNXXU2ARF7</value>
    <value rcount="4" fwsize="524681746">A600FNXXU3BSE2/A600FNOXM3BSE2/A600FNXXU3BSD2</value>
    ....
</upgrade>
```

Everything from `upgrade` to `</upgrade>`

Comment: Can you add an example of the xml to the question.

Comment: http://fota-cloud-dn.ospserver.net/firmware/SEB/SM-A600FN/version.test.xml

Comment: Once you've got the `update` element you need to get all the `value` elements under it and enumerate them.

Comment: Your question and sample xml are different. The `InnerText` of sample is `111/222/333` while your example is `111222333`.

Comment: @LouisGo ok sorry will edit

Comment: This is an easy task, you may use `string.Replace` to replace `/` to `Environment.NewLine`. Is it answered your question?

Comment: @JohnBielowski in that case you can just use `String.Split()` with `/` as the separator and use `File.WriteAllLines`. What are you trying to do thoug? Extranct each node to a separate file, all nodes to the same file or just the first node? That's much more interesting code

Comment: @LouisGo some do not have the ```/``` at the end because its last value.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos check the last character before ```</value>``` It's not a ```/```

Comment: @JohnBielowski why would that matter? You don't need to write anything after that or do you? Even so, `WriteAllLines` would write all array elements to separate lines. Almost the same as replacing `/` with `\n`. The question is incomplete and the real example doesn't contain just a single string, it contains multiple `value` elements. Perhaps the real question is how to find and export all `value`s?

Comment: @JohnBielowski Then you just need to append another newline in the end of each `InnerText`.

Comment: @LouisGo How can I do that? I have just 1 ```string k = z[0].InnerText;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
var data = xmlDocument2.SelectNodes("/versioninfo/firmware/version/upgrade/value")
                        .Cast<XmlElement>()
                        .SelectMany(x=>x.InnerText.Split('/').Select(c=>$"{c}/"));

File.WriteAllLines(filePath,data);
```

Sample Output

```
A600FNXXU5CTA1/
A600FNOXM5CTA1/
A600FNXXU5CTA1/
A600FNXXU2ARG5/
A600FNOXM2ARF7/
A600FNXXU2ARF7/
A600FNXXU3BSE2/
A600FNOXM3BSE2/
A600FNXXU3BSD2/
A600FNXXU0ARCB/
A600FNOXM0ARCB/
A600FNXXU0ARCB/
.....
.....
.....
```